# What is the advantage of using wp_mail?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, wp-mail

What is the advantage of using `wp_mail()` over `mail()`. Codex says they're similar, but they seem to be *very* similar.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`wp_mail()` is a pluggable function: It can be replaced by plugins. That’s useful in cases where the regular `mail()` doesn’t work (good enough), for example when you need extra authentication details. Example: [WP Mail SMTP](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/)

`wp_mail()` uses [PHPMailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/) by default, a sophisticated PHP class which offers a lot of useful preprocessing and workarounds for cases where `mail()` is too simple (UTF-8 encoded subject lines, attachments and so on). Just take a look at the [bug tracker](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?atid=385707&group_id=26031&func=browse) to get an idea about the complexity of these tasks.

`wp_mail` offers some hooks for other plugins to change different values:

- `'wp_mail'`
- `'wp_mail_from'`
- `'wp_mail_from_name'` [use case](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/12368/73)
- `'wp_mail_content_type'`
- `'wp_mail_charset'`
- `'phpmailer_init'` *(an action)*

In short: **Use `wp_mail()` for interoperability.**