# email wordpress users using BCC

Tags: email, notifications

I am currently using the below code to email users when a new post is published, but I need it to BCC all users and not TO all users. Any ideas?

```
function email_members($post_ID)  {
global $wpdb;
$usersarray = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT user_email FROM $wpdb->users;");
$users = implode(",", $usersarray);
mail($users, "New WordPress recipe online!", 'A new recipe have been published on http://www.wprecipes.com');
return $post_ID;
}

add_action('publish_post', 'email_members');
```

Answer (score 3):

First: Don’t use `mail()`. [Use `wp_mail()`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45289/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-wp-mail/45291#45291) instead.

```
wp_mail( 
    // Send it to yourself
    get_option( 'admin_email' ), 
    'Your subject', 
    'Your message', 
    // extra headers
    array (
        'Bcc:' . implode( ",", $usersarray ),
        'From:' . get_option( 'admin_email' )
    ) 
);
```

Comment: So is this the way it should look?

`function email_members($post_ID)  {
global $wpdb;
$usersarray = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT user_email FROM $wpdb->users;");
$users = implode(",", $usersarray);

wp_mail( 
    // Send it to yourself
    get_option( 'admin_email' ), 
    'Your subject', 
    'Your message', 
    // extra headers
    array (
        'Bcc:' . implode( ",", $usersarray ),
        'From:' . get_option( 'admin_email' )
    ) 
);
return $post_ID;
}

add_action('publish_post', 'email_members');`

Comment: @Shae Yeah, seems to be okay. You don’t have to return anything on an action.