# How can I get taxonomy terms and custom field values of a newly created post

Tags: custom-post-types, publish

I created a system where people can post a CPT via a frontend form.

Now, a mail has to be sent out to inform about this CPT.

I tried this approach, which works, but I cannot get to the custom field value, nor the taxonomy that's being set through the form. That info is needed in the mail.

It seems that they don't exist when the post is published. How to resolve this?

[How to auto send email when publishing a custom post type?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/100644/how-to-auto-send-email-when-publishing-a-custom-post-type/184807#184807)

Comment: You have post object then you can retrieve custom fields and custom taxonomy! You tried that ?

Comment: Yep. That's how I noticed. 
http://pastie.org/10103947

This is what's in the mail
The (MISSING) stuff is what I edited in for this answer, but those fields are blank.

`code`new entry!

Uploaded by user001 - [hismailaddress@gmail.com]
Approval Status : CUSTOM FIELD VALUE NOT SET.. MISSING.
-------------------------------------------------------
[ignore, for development purposes]

term slug :  - (MISSING)
term id : (MISSING)
old status: draft 

new status: publish`code`

Comment: Hence, the post object is available, but the meta info isn't ...

Comment: It's depend on when you are updating post meta. Most people do it on `save_post` and it is called after `transition_post_status` so you won't get the custom meta values. try changing your hooks it may work!