# Why custom creation e-mail template file comes to mail box as html code?

Tags: plugin-development

I work on plugin development for sent user notifications after the new post_type is published. And now I have some stake. For clients important to have a plugin options page for configuration the mail body.  Okay, it's done. But why the mail comes to the mailbox as HTML code? For sending mail I use : (I get the code here: [How to auto send email when publishing a custom post type](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/100644/how-to-auto-send-email-when-publishing-a-custom-post-type?fbclid=IwAR0myh1B-KupsVzDQrY8V4herqN53ICrMXfo-CQb_MStukaVo7E2z7WOwPM))

```
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'send_mails_on_publish', 10, 3 );

  function send_mails_on_publish( $new_status, $old_status, $post ){
    if ( 'publish' !== $new_status or 'publish' === $old_status
    or 'opportunity' !== get_post_type( $post ) )
    return;
$subscribers = get_users( array ( 'role' => 'subscriber_basic' ) );
$emails      = array ();
$post_meta_values =  get_post_meta($post);

    foreach ( $subscribers as $subscriber )
       $emails[] = $subscriber->user_email;
       $message = file_get_contents('tpl-mail.php', true);
       wp_mail( $emails, 'New entry!', $message );
 }
```

tpl-mail.php - this is the file with the HTML mail template. tpl-mail.php placed in the plugin root directory.  And everything works, but instead of a normal e-mail, the HTML mail arrives. Please help to solve why?

Comment: `file_get_contents` won't execute the PHP in `tpl-mail.php`, but also `wp_mail` sends plaintext emails by default, you need extra steps to explicitly state that it's a HTML email, but that's already been asked on the site many times with good answers already written

Comment: @TomJNowell Thanks a lot, and sorry for duplication of the question.