# Should I use the standard wp_mail() function for a premium theme?

Tags: email, premium

I am creating a premium theme that includes a Contact page template. Currently, I am using the `wp_mail()` function to send the contact email to the administrator-specified email address.

Basically, I am wondering if the `wp_mail()` function is the best/expected choice for implementing email functionality in a premium WordPress theme? If it is not, what would be the better option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should use `wp_mail()`. There is no difference between a premium theme and a regular theme in this point. `wp_mail()` has [many advantages](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/45291/73) and your clients will rely on it. If you break it, many plugins will not work anymore.

Besides that, it is not the job of a *theme* to change this functionality. There are plugins to replace the function.