# publish_post action doesn't work

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, actions

i'm developing a small plugin which will send email to users when a new magazine is published.

i made a post type name "magazine" on the theme functions.php.
and i wrote a plugin for email subscriptions.

code:

```
function newsletter_sendEmails($post_id)
{
    $post = get_post($post_id);

    if ($post->post_type == 'magazine')
    {
        mail( "dor@zuberi.me", "מגזין חדש", "התפרסם מגזין חדש!" );
    }
}

add_action('publish_post', 'newsletter_sendEmails');
```

but from some reason i don't get the email when i publish a new magazine, why is that?

Comment: What happens if you [use `wp_mail()`](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/47200/73) as you should?

Answer (score 3):

It's never fired since the hook you need is not `publish_post` but `publish_magazine` which is actually `{$new_status}_{$post_type}` hook. So try `publish_magazine`

**update:** also you don't need to use get_post since you the hook passes the `$post` object to the function as a second parameter. take a look at [**`wp_transition_post_status()`**](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/post.php#L3023)

and if that's not working then you have something else going wrong.

Comment: doesn't work either :\