# Using the 'draft_to_publish' hook (post status transition)

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, hooks, actions

I am trying to use the draft_to_publish hook (http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions) to run a function when a post that is a draft becomes published. This hook does not appear to be working:

```
add_action('draft_to_publish', 'myFunction');
```

When I use this in my plug-in, myFunction is never fired. I have used/tested the function before. I know it is the hook, not the contents of myFunction.

All 'solutions' I found just link to the Codex page above. Any ideas about why this hook is not working?

**Edit:**
Here is an example. It the email will not be sent, because the action never fires:

```
function myfunction () {
        $to = "recipient@example.com";
        $subject = "Hi!";
        $body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";
        if (mail($to, $subject, $body)) {
          echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
         } else {
          echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
         }
    }
add_action('draft_to_publish', 'myFunction');
```

Comment: There is not enough information to answer your question. Please try to add more detail, more code, and some [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress).

Comment: What happens if you use `wp_mail()` as [you should](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/45291/73)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You certainly have the right hook, but keep in mind that you are hooking your functionality specifically to the `draft_to_publish` action, i.e. to the specific case of a post-object pre-existing in the database with `draft` status being updated to `publish`. Note that this action ignores drafts which are automatically saved by Wordpress when a new post is created - these "drafts" have a `post_status` of `auto-draft`.

I'm not exactly sure how you've been debugging the issue up to this point, but if you haven't already, I would recommend verifying that the action itself is firing when you expect it to, perhaps by attaching some simple, arbitrary, and obvious function to it:

```
function kill_wp( $post ) {
  die( 'draft_to_publish fired for post #' . $post['ID'] . ' entitled, "' . $post['post_title'] . '"' );
}
add_action( 'draft_to_publish', 'kill_wp' );
```

That said, part of your problem may lie in capitalization - the action callback in your example references the function `myFunction` while the function that is defined has been named `myfunction`.

Though I am not sure as to what you are trying to accomplish, you could alternately attempt to attach your functionality to [the generic action `transition_post_status`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions#transition_post_status_Hook) which gets passed the the new status of the post, the previous status of the post, and the post object such that you would have something similar to

```
function wpse77561_mail_on_publish( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
  if (get_post_type($post) !== 'post')
        return;    //Don't touch anything that's not a post (i.e. ignore links and attachments and whatnot )

    //If some variety of a draft is being published, dispatch an email
    if( ( 'draft' === $old_status || 'auto-draft' === $old_status ) && $new_status === 'publish' ) {
        $to      = 'recipient@example.com';
        $subject = 'Hi!';
        $body    = 'Hi,' . chr(10) . chr(10) . 'How are you?';

        if( wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body ) ) {
            echo('<p>Message successfully sent!</p>');
        } else {
            echo('<p>Message delivery failed...</p>');
        }
    }
}
add_action('transition_post_status', 'wpse77561_mail_on_publish');
```

There are also a number of tools available that might grant you more insight into Wordpress' action execution such as the [action hooks inspector](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/debug-bar-action-hooks/) for the [Debug Bar](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/debug-bar/) plugin.

Comment: @bosco , it should `my_function( $strNewStatus, $strOldStatus, $post )` not `my_function( $strOldStatus, $strNewStatus, $post )`. Thank you.

Comment: Nice catch, @Eray! Updated with the proper parameter order and to use the same variables as the Codex.

Comment: Actually, this is wrong: "Note that this action [draft_to_publish] ignores drafts which are automatically saved by Wordpress when a new post is created - these 'drafts' have a post_status of auto-draft." It does in fact include those posts too. I've tested it. So I'm using `draft_to_publish` without problems. However, in my case I'm also using the hook `publish_to_publish` so that I fetch clicks to 'Update' a blog post as well.