# Mail not sent when I set HTML headers

Tags: php, wp-mail, email

```
$subject = get_the_title(); 
$sender_name = get_bloginfo('name');
$blog_url = get_bloginfo('url');

$to      = 'myemail@mydomainname.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: '.$sender_name.' <no-reply@'.$blog_url.'>' . "\r\n";

$headersssssssssssss = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

When I use the `$headersssssssssssss` variable as a parameter in the `mail()` function, it works and sends an E-Mail.
But when I use `$headers` as a parameter, it does not.

Note: I have already tried using `wp_mail` instead, with the same results.

```
if( mail($to, $subject, $message, $headersssssssssssss) )
{
    echo '<script>alert("mail sent success!");</script>';
} else {
    echo '<script>alert("mail where not sent");</script>';
} 

exit;
```

Comment: [What is the advantage of using wp_mail?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/45291/73)

Comment: I guess this mainly is a server configuration issue.

Answer (score 4):

There's the [`wp_mail()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail) function in WordPress. The headers have to be added as array without trailing `\n\r` or similar.

#### Example

```
wp_mail(
    'test@example.com',
    'Hello World!',
    'Just saying...',
    array(
        'MIME-Version: 1.0',
        'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1',
        sprintf(
            'From: %s <no-reply@%s>',
            get_bloginfo('name'),
            site_url()
        ),
        sprintf( 'X-Mailer: PHP/%s', phpversion() ),
     )
);
```

To change the content type you could as well use a filter:

```
<?php
/* Plugin Name: WP Mail Content Type text/html */
function wpse_97789_mail_contenttype( $content_type )
{
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );
    return 'text/html';
}

// Then, whereever you need it, just add the filter before calling the function
// It removes itself after firing once
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'wpse_97789_mail_contenttype' );
wp_mail(
    'test@example.com',
    'Hello World!',
    'Just saying...',
    array(
        'MIME-Version: 1.0',
        sprintf(
            'From: %s <no-reply@%s>',
            get_bloginfo('name'),
            site_url()
        ),
        sprintf( 'X-Mailer: PHP/%s', phpversion() ),
    )
);
```

Comment: still else working here in code 
[see image-result](http://s16.postimg.org/lc6l6vsb9/return_result.jpg)

Comment: @RameezSOOMRO Please make sure your server is set up properly.

Comment: mail were sent if i dont' add html headers, but how i can check server setup properly because i am using shared hosting...

Comment: Sorry, but this question is outside the scope of this site.

Comment: can you please send me url of related solution, but I am also using contact form 7 plugin its work fine in same site with html headers...

Comment: I have same issue, But the same code works in another sub domain of the same host wordpress installation. I disabled all the plugin except my code. Still no luck