# email sends from wordpress@domain.com even though I have it set to something else

Tags: email

My wordpress settings email is contact@domain.com. When I search my entire database for the email of wordpress@domain.com, it does not exist.

Yet my registration emails are still sent from wordpress@domain.com for some reason.

The only thing I can think of is that when I look in my wp_users table, I have no user with the ID of 1. I believe this is the default admin ID. I'm not sure who did it or when, but I think the default admin was deleted a long time ago and I just made my username admin. Perhaps if wordpress doesn't find an admin email, it automatically goes to wordpress@?

I'm confused with this one.

Answer (score 6):

Ok, then you can try this
You can set the header, just not with a parameter. WordPress uses "hooks" and the hooks you need are 'wp_mail_from' and 'wp_mail_from_name' hooks.

Here are the hooks you might add to your theme's functions.php file to modify the "From:" header when using wp_mail() to the email address Greg j :

```
add_filter('wp_mail_from','yoursite_wp_mail_from');
function yoursite_wp_mail_from($content_type) {
  return 'abc@example.com';
}
add_filter('wp_mail_from_name','yoursite_wp_mail_from_name');
function yoursite_wp_mail_from_name($name) {
  return 'Greg j';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

WordPress does not look at your admin email, it uses the made-up address, each time `wp_mail()` was called without a `From` header.

```
// From email and name
// If we don't have a name from the input headers
if ( !isset( $from_name ) )
    $from_name = 'WordPress';

/* If we don't have an email from the input headers default to wordpress@$sitename
 * Some hosts will block outgoing mail from this address if it doesn't exist but
 * there's no easy alternative. Defaulting to admin_email might appear to be another
 * option but some hosts may refuse to relay mail from an unknown domain. See
 * http://trac.wordpress.org/ticket/5007.
 */

if ( !isset( $from_email ) ) {
    // Get the site domain and get rid of www.
    $sitename = strtolower( $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] );
    if ( substr( $sitename, 0, 4 ) == 'www.' ) {
        $sitename = substr( $sitename, 4 );
    }

    $from_email = 'wordpress@' . $sitename;
}
```

You can filter that from address and the name: [changing notification emails from WordPress <wordpress>@mydomain.net to something else](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12368/changing-notification-emails-from-wordpress-wordpressmydomain-net-to-somethin)

In some cases you *must* filter it: when your domain name is `www.tld`, WordPress will strip the `www.` and use an email address `wordpress@tld`.